# How to set parameters for NpgsqlCommand when the number of columns are not fixed

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am trying to insert values into the database but the problem is that the input is variable and can change. For example, for the first row to be inserted it has 15 columns but the next has 12 columns. Except for a few, none of the other columns are compulsory.

What I am trying to do is this, have a string with the barebone insert query

```
private static string INSERT_QUERY = "INSERT INTO table (cols) VALUES (@vals)";

using var query = new NpgsqlCommand(INSERT_QUERY.Replace("cols", string.Join(",", columnsAndValues[0])), rawConnection)
            {
                Parameters =
                {
                    new ("vals", columnsAndValues[1])
                }
            };
var recordsAffected = await query.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

The array columnsAndValues are what is parsed by the service, with input from the client. Index 0 is the column fields and 1 is the values.
The error I am facing is this, Npgsql.PostgresException: '42601: INSERT has more target columns than expressions. What I am suspecting is that, in the query there are "x" number of columns but there are just 1 value.

Is there a way to subvert this?

We had contract classes before, we used to create an object of the contract class and then the client used to send that, so that had fixed number of columns and values but we scrapped that because altering 1 column in the table would mean, the same change had to be updated in the codebase as well, so two changes/PR for each updation and based on past history we used to have multiple changes every quarter.

Comment: The database has to have all the columns.  You are adding columns that do not exist in the database.  You first have to add the new columns to the database before you can add the rows containing the columns.

Comment: The database does have all the columns. If I was not clear, database has 55 cols, but the input will not always have the 55 cols, and the number of cols in the input varies, I do not have any control on the data that is being fed unfortunately

Comment: You are filling rows in the database.  The row could be an array of 55 items when you have all the columns.  When the data is not 55 you have to be able to indicate which piece of data goes into which columns.  You could send 55 columns and add blanks where data is missing.  Or you can label each column by name.  Read following : https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html#positional-and-named-placeholders

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `@vals` with the number of column values to be inserted, and you need to add those all as parameters.

```cs
var sql = INSERT_QUERY
    .Replace("cols", string.Join(",", columnsAndValues[0]))
    .Replace("@vals", string.Join(",", columnsAndValues[0].Select(c => "@" + c)));

using var query = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, rawConnection);
for (var i = 0; i < columnsAndValues[0].Length; i++)
    query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + columnsAndValues[0][i], columnsWithValues[1][i]); 

var recordsAffected = await query.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

I would advise you **not to do this**. You are much better off just hard-coding the columns, as then you can also specify the parameter types. Even better: if you are just doing an insert then [use a bulk copy mechanism](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html), which will be much much faster.